# Codeigniter get name from other table in overview

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im getting a list from my database with the following (in my controller):

```
$view["interactions"] = $this->interacties->getInteractionsId($id);
```

This gives an array with everything in my database in the table 'interactions'.

Im posting this to my view with the following foreach loop:

```
<?php if($interactions): ?>
   <?php foreach($interactions as $interaction): ?>
      <tr class="gradeX">
         <td><a href="<?=site_url('interactie/single/'.$interaction['id'])?>"><?=$interaction['datum']?></a></td>
         <td><?=$interaction['gebruikers_id']?></td>
         <td><?=$interaction['gesproken_met']?></td>
         <td><?=$interaction['interactie']?></td>
      </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
   <p>Geen interacties</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This works fine, but now I want to change the `$interaction['gebruikers_id']` to a name which is in my 'users' table which is called 'naam'.  Normaly I would get the id and use another get function.  But because this is in a foreach loop I'm not sure how to do this.

This is the function in the Model:

```
public function getInteractionsId($id) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('bedrijf_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('interacties');

    return $query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query-> result_array() : FALSE;

}
```

Comment: You could use a join in your query so that the result of `getInteractions` also contains the user's name. Please show the code for that function if you want suggestions on how to do that.

Comment: I added the function, im not that familiar with the join function in CI, so maybe you could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your model function to this:

```
public function getInteractionsId($id) {
  $this->db->select('interacties.*, gebruikers.naam');
  $this->db->join('gebruikers', 'interacties.gebruikers_id = gebruikers.id');
  $this->db->where('bedrijf_id', $id);
  $query = $this->db->get('interacties');
  return $query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query-> result_array() : FALSE;
}
```

You can do this in your view:

```
<?=$interaction['naam']?>
```

If you are not familiar with the basics of database joins, check out [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Comment: that worked 100%, thanks alot. And thanks for the article link :).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in a view, you should only do presentation stuff, no further database calls.

You could do this in the controller in an extra `foreach` loop.

Still, the best option IMHO is to patch your method getInteractionsId() to **join with users table** so that you will have both $interaction['gebruikers_id'] and $interaction['users_naam'].

Whatever you end up to, think of [fat models and skinny controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568553/mvc-in-php-fat-model-or-fat-controller).